# Rails Shopify App Update Shop Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, shopify

I am trying to make sure that every Shop model is updated with the information I want to have when they open their app. The way I am doing this is by checking to see if the Shop model is `customer_created = true`

The problem is, is that when I run a method to check and update the Shop model, it isn't working.

The Shop model is not being updated when I go to index.html.erb for some reason, but it is returning the correct Shop model. How can I get it to update the Shop, when necessary?

Controller

```
class HomeController < ShopifyApp::AuthenticatedController
  include ApplicationHelper

  def index
    @shop = Shop.updated(current_shop)
    if @shop.save
      redirect_to current_products_path
    end
  end
...
```

When the visitor has the app installed and visits index.html.erb, this is supposed to make sure the shop is completely updated.
Here is the shop.rb

```
class Shop < ActiveRecord::Base
  include ShopifyApp::Shop
  include ShopifyApp::SessionStorage

  def self.updated(shop)
    @the_shop = shop
    current_shop_api = ShopifyAPI::Shop.current
    unless @the_shop.customer_created
      @the_shop.customer_created = true
      @the_shop.email = current_shop_api.email
      @the_shop.currency = current_shop_api.currency
      @the_shop.domain = current_shop_api.domain
      @the_shop.country_name = current_shop_api.country_name
      @the_shop.money_format = current_shop_api.money_format
      @the_shop.money_with_currency_format = current_shop_api.money_with_currency_format
      @the_shop.name = current_shop_api.name
      @the_shop.shop_owner = current_shop_api.shop_owner
      @the_shop.timezone = current_shop_api.timezone
      @the_shop.save
    end
    return @the_shop
  end
end
```

Lastly, here are the helper methods being used

```
def current_shop
    return Shop.find_by(shopify_domain: ShopifyAPI::Shop.current.domain)
end

def current_shop_api
    return ShopifyAPI::Shop.current
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You could save yourself a huge amount of trouble and just make a single API query to have all the info about the shop. Why keep a version of that in your DB? Makes no sense. Your App is not adding value with that data so just get it live when you need it.

Comment: I'm going to be adding products to users' stores, and want to have that information on my end because I will be charging them per sale based off product and using that info to send through my fulfillment software.

Comment: Right.. but it makes zero sense to keep that information around, and worry about it's freshness, when you can just make an API call and get that data to work with. In other words, you are making a mountain out of a molehill. Why make so much work for yourself when you clearly have bigger fish to fry.

Comment: Because I want to store sales per store, revenue I have made per store, store their domain names, email addresses, etc. for my own use. It a store owner no longer is using my service, I wouldn't have access to their email to try to win them back, know they are past subscriber, etc.